# Filling google chart chartArea with a gradient

Tags: svg, background, google-visualization, gradient, fill

I've been exploring the features of google charts and now I'm trying to customize a scatter chart. 
I got the following function:

```
function drawScatterChart(){
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Chance', 'Impact'],
          [ 5,      4],
          [ 1,      2]
        ]);
    var options = {
          hAxis: {title: 'Chance', minValue: 0, maxValue: 5},
          vAxis: {title: 'Impact', minValue: 0, maxValue: 5},
          legend: 'none',
          'chartArea' : { 'backgroundColor' : '#F4F4F4' } 
        };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('scatter_chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

This succesfully changes the background color of only the chartArea to gray, which is great. But now I'd like to implement a gradient that goes from the left bottom to the top right of the chart and containing 3 colors (green to yellow to red).

Is there any way to hack this into the chart since I've been trying to find anything in the documentation and only could find some old documentation (namely: https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_params) but couldn't find a way to implement this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This chart will be created using SVG.
In SVG gradients will be created via the `<linearGradient/>`-element.

Take a look at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-gradients.html to see how these elements look like.

What you can do: 
When the chart has been drawn inject a   `<linearGradient/>` into the `<defs/>` .

The styles may be set via CSS, but note: SVG has it's own style-properties, see: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-and-css.html

Demo:

---

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  var   container  = document.getElementById('chart_div'),
        data       = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                      ['Chance', 'Impact'],
                      [ 5,      4],
                      [ 1,      2]
                    ]),
        options    = {
                      hAxis: {title: 'Chance', minValue: 0, maxValue: 5},
                      vAxis: {title: 'Impact', minValue: 0, maxValue: 5},
                      legend: 'none'
                     },
        chart      = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(container,options),
        createSVG  = function(n,a,b){
                      var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
                          e     = document.createElementNS (xmlns, n);
                      for(var k in a){
                        e.setAttributeNS (null, k,a[k]);
                      }
                      for(var k in b){
                        e.setAttribute (k,b[k]);
                      }
                      return e;
                    };

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function(){
    
    var gradient  =createSVG('linearGradient',{  
                                x1:0,y1:1,x2:1,y2:0
                              },{
                                id:'fx'
                              }
                            );
    document.getElementById('chart_div')
      .querySelector('svg>defs').appendChild(gradient);
    gradient.appendChild(createSVG('stop',{offset:'0%'}));
    gradient.appendChild(createSVG('stop',{offset:'50%'}));
    gradient.appendChild(createSVG('stop',{offset:'100%'}));
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```css
html,body,#chart_div{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#chart_div svg>g>rect { 
    fill: url(#fx) !important;
    fill-opacity:1 !important;
}

#fx stop:nth-child(1){ 
  stop-color: green; 
}
                
#fx stop:nth-child(2){ 
  stop-color: yellow;
}

#fx stop:nth-child(3){ 
  stop-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div  id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I just want to note that this doesn't work in firefox. I'm currently trying to figure out what is going wrong, but for any other browser this is a very good solution. Weirdly enough the code snippet does work in firefox.

Comment: Misterious, I visit this page in FF and when I run the snippet I see ....a gradient

Comment: I know, but the gradient does show up in chrome, but not in firefox, while it shows up on both browsers when running the code at stackoverflow :/

Comment: @Dr.Molle, great work. I was able to utilize the gradient background fill for one of iOS app. It worked as a charm.

Comment: DUUUUUDE! How did you figure this out!?  Amazing! Thanks!!!     BTW: What is that createSVG stuff?